# How to remove notices and warnings from the end of PHP survey?

Tags: php, html, mysql, undefined

I have following code:

```
<?php

include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$_SESSION['pollid'] = (int) $_GET['pollid'];
$questions = array();

if (!isset($_SESSION['answering'])) 
{
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * from katse_kysimused where kysimustik_id="' . $_SESSION['pollid'] . '"');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $questions[] = $row['kysimus'];
    }
    $_SESSION['answering']['questions'] = $questions;
    $_SESSION['answering']['index']     = 0;
    $_SESSION['answering']['count']     = count($questions);
}

$answer  = $_POST['answer'];
$x       = $_SESSION['answering']['index'];
$result3 = mysql_query('SELECT tyyp_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x] . '"');
$type    = mysql_result($result3, 0);

if ($type == '3') 
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/valikvastustega_kysimusele_vastamine.php'>";
}

if ($type == '1') 
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/tekstkysimusele_vastamine2.php'>";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    if(isset($_POST['option'])) 
    {
        $answer = $_POST['option'];
    }
    $result2 = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x -1] . '"');
    $q_id    = mysql_result($result2, 0);
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO katse_vastused2 (id, vastus,kysimus_id, vastustik_id) VALUES (NULL,"' . $answer . '","' . $q_id . '","1")');
}

$_SESSION['answering']['index']++;

?>
```

What this code does is showing questions from database which have `kysimustik_id="' . $_SESSION['pollid']`. Everything works the way it has to (There are two pieces of code in adition, one for showing and answering text questions and one for radio button questions.)

My problem is that I want it to echo out that Survey is over, when all questions have answer, but I dont know how I should rearrange my code to do it. Right now I get these errors, when all questions are answered:

```
Notice: Undefined index: answer in C:\xampp2\htdocs\Praks\answering.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\Praks\answering.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 7 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\Praks\answering.php on line 17
```

I tried to change code to that:

```
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$_SESSION['pollid']=(int) $_GET['pollid'];
$questions = array();

if (!isset($_SESSION['answering'])) 
{
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * from katse_kysimused where kysimustik_id="' . $_SESSION['pollid'] . '"');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $questions[] = $row['kysimus'];
    }
    $_SESSION['answering']['questions'] = $questions;
    $_SESSION['answering']['index']     = 0;
    $_SESSION['answering']['count']     = count($questions);
}

if ($_SESSION['answering']['index']<$_SESSION['answering']['count']) 
{
    $answer  = $_POST['answer'];
    $x       = $_SESSION['answering']['index'];
    $result3 = mysql_query('SELECT tyyp_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x] . '"');
    $type    = mysql_result($result3, 0);

    if ($type == '3') 
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/valikvastustega_kysimusele_vastamine.php'>";
    }

    if ($type == '1') 
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/tekstkysimusele_vastamine2.php'>";
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['option']))
        {
            $answer=$_POST['option'];
        }

        $result2 = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x -1] . '"');
        $q_id = mysql_result($result2, 0);
        mysql_query('INSERT INTO katse_vastused2 (id, vastus,kysimus_id, vastustik_id) VALUES (NULL,"' . $answer . '","' . $q_id . '","1")');
    }

    $_SESSION['answering']['index']++;
}

else
    echo 'Küsitlus lõppenud';
?>
```

But I still get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: pollid in C:\xampp2\htdocs\Praks\answering.php on line 3
```

I don't know how I should rearrange things to lose this notice, without messing anything up.

And second problem that appears after this change is that the last answer of survey wont be inserted into database. I understand why it happens, but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: This will appear because your, get variable is not set, and its index value, pollid not found, you just wrote down ini_set("error_reporting",0); at the starting of the file, so that it will hide all your warnings.

Comment: By the way, you've got a missing } to close the 'if' after 'if ($type=='1') { ... }'

Comment: try adding session_start() at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change (line 2 and 3)

```
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$_SESSION['pollid']=(int) $_GET['pollid'];
```

into

```
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
if (isset($_GET['pollid']))
    $_SESSION['pollid']=(int) $_GET['pollid'];
else
    $_SESSION['pollid'] = 0;
```

Also this script allows sql injection and (probably) also XSS (security!) and uses a deprecated api to mysql.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_GET['pollid']))
    $_SESSION['pollid']=(int) $_GET['pollid'];
else
    $_SESSION['pollid'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`if (!isset($_SESSION['answering'])) {`

Use:

`if (empty($_SESSION['answering'])) {`

http://www.php.net/isset

http://www.php.net/empty

Comment: I can't understand this answer, empty and !isset are subtley different, but won't make a difference if the variable/key doesn't exist. More importantly though,  the warnings don't come from that line.